# How do I stand up for myself against my manager while still taking accountability for my mistake?

Tags: communication, conflict, conflict-resolution

As with a lot of workplaces, the work we do at my company is very much a team effort.

I was assigned to semi-lead a cross-team project with one other team. I say semi-lead because while I was the one appointing stuff and communicating with the other team we collaborated with, my 2 managers still were to have the final say in what the final product was to be.

Throughout this whole process, I did my best to communicate with them (we worked remotely this week so everything was via Slack), but because they’re both very busy, replied would come slow, and the other team would constantly have to wait for approvals (from my managers via myself). I was getting frustrated for them.

Eventually, Manager B gave their input, and I responded. Asked a question back. No response. Manager A then finally gets back to the Slack group chat, 10 hours later at 9PM!

Their message read something along the lines of:

[Feedback on project] and this will be the last revision for this because this needs to be shipped out ASAP. We need to test these products by Thursday and you held us back from getting everything in top shape by not acting on this project with urgency. Manager B and myself are extremely busy, so you could have tagged us more on Slack if you needed us to respond.

—

I understand where they’re coming from saying I didn’t treat it with urgency, and in the morning I will respond to it (I’m sorry but I am not here to be responding to Slack messages at 9PM) and apologize for not being more on top of it. But I also feel like if the Slack group chat was created for us to communicate about the project, should they not also have been on top of it? I understand they have other things they’re busy with outside of this project—I do too! But am I wrong to think that they also played a role here? All approvals were to be run by them first, and they both were not very responsive, plus made it sound like it was my fault for not making sure that they respond.

How do I communicate this frustration to my manager without sounding like I’m trying to transfer the blame to them? Ultimately I just want to give feedback to make sure it’s understood that while I’m taking accountability for where I went wrong, I also want them to see that this is a team thing and the blame doesn’t solely fall on me, and so that in the future all parties know where to improve?

Comment: You used the word "**blame**". Did any failure occur ? Did any damage happen to the product or anyone's reputation ? If yes, did anyone blame you for anything yet ?

Comment: Well I felt pretty blamed/accused for being the one who held the project back. No damage to the product or anyone’s reputation. I just would like to know how to address this to my manager and point out that while perhaps I was not more persistent in getting responses from them, they should’ve also been on top of their tasks and messages. If I should be held accountable, they should be too, no?

Comment: Prior to this reply from Manager A, were you aware of the urgency on the project? If so, did you indicate in your messages the level of urgency that you needed a reply from the managers?

Comment: As an aside, you need to remove the concept of "semi-lead" from your vocabulary. Thinking that way starts you off on the wrong foot. You are the lead  and you are responsible. Maybe some of the decisions that you wanted your managers to make were ones that you could have made if you had accepted full responsibility. I don't mean that to be harsh; I just have made that mistake before myself :) It is much easier to apologize for making a wrong choice because you wanted to keep the project on track than it is to defend doing nothing while waiting on someone else's decision.

Comment: "If I should be held accountable, they should be too, no? " -- yes, but that's _their_ managers' responsibility. Not yours.

Answer (score 5):

As you have noticed, a Slack group chat is a bad way to communicate in your case. As a project manager (your position sounds like it) you are responsible for keeping the project on track. If you need faster feedback from your managers, it's your responsibility to get it. Writing into a chat (which may not even trigger a notification) once and then waiting for 10 hours IS a mistake.

When it's urgent, use all communication methods available. Start with chat, email, whatever. But when there is no reaction for a reasonable timeframe, get on the phone and call. Or at least use notification features in your preferred communication app.

**How to adress that with management:**

Don't start to justify yourself, or do some half excuses ("I'm sorry, but..."). Move forward. This will not be the last time you'll need feedback on time critical stuff. Ask what they want from you in the future, how you can get stuff done faster. Maybe it's also time to talk about delegation. Do they really need to check everything? Do two managers need to check it? Can't it be just one?

Comment: Exactly.  Defensiveness is useless here and potentially harmful. Say oops, ask for advice on how to improve, move on. Humans make mistakes, and that's embarrassing. But "good judgement comes from experience, and experience comes from bad judgement." Learn, let go, and do better next time.